# Error installing xtradb percona cluster

Tags: mysql, percona, centos, percona-server

I have 2 nodes to join percona cluster . I installed them successfully , node 1 was able to start working . when I switched to node 2 configuration, I fixed the file my.cnf

```
cat >>/etc/my.cnf<<EOF
[mysqld]
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera3/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name=democluster
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://node1,node2
wsrep_node_name=centosvm02
wsrep_node_address=node2
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth=user:123abc@A
pxc_strict_mode=ENFORCING
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
EOF
```

After fixing the file, I tried to run systemctl start mysql , and it gave me an error
job for mysql.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process. see "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
tôi đã mở theo gợi ý journalctl -xe
[image]

Comment: How did you install? Please provide exact commands.

Comment: I downloaded the percona xtraDB cluster 5.7 full package from the website